# Problem change automatically the menu Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have two different menus. I want the first menu when the customer login, and the second where a business login.

All works almost perfectly, the problem is: when a business login then logout and login with a customer account, the menu doesn't change immediately I need to close an open the app.

The first one :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_map_24"
        android:title="@string/title_map" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="@string/title_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_profil"/>

</menu>
```

The second one :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
        android:title="@string/title_send"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_stat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_stat_alt_24"
        android:title="@string/title_stat"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profil_business"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_profil"/>

</menu>
```

Login Activity :

```
String uRl = "http://10.0.2.2/Test/login.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if(!response.equals("Login Success")){

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){

                            JSONObject ob = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            UserModel user = new UserModel(ob.getInt("userID"));

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (user.getUserID()!=0){
                                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_USERID", 0);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                editor.putInt("userID", user.getUserID());
                                editor.commit();
                            }


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error :"+e);
                    }

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_ISCONNECTED", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isConnected", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    finish();

                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("LOGIN", pseudo);
                return param;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

MainActivity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        businessOK=true;

        SharedPreferences settings2 = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_BUSINESSID", 0);
        int test2 = settings2.getInt("businessID", 0);

        if (test2!=0){
            navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu_business);

            AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_send, R.id.navigation_stat, R.id.navigation_profil_business)
                    .build();

        }
        else
        {
            navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu);

            AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_search, R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_profil)
                    .build();

        }
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_ISCONNECTED", 0);
        boolean bool = settings.getBoolean("isConnected", false);
        isConnected=bool;

        SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_USERID", 0);
        int test = settings1.getInt("userID", 0);
        UserModel.setTheUserID(test);

        SharedPreferences settings2 = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_BUSINESSID", 0);
        int test2 = settings2.getInt("businessID", 0);
        BusinessModel.setTheBusinessID(test2);

        SharedPreferences settings3 = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_CUSTOMERID", 0);
        int test3 = settings3.getInt("customerID", 0);
        Customer.setTheCustomerID(test3);


        if (!isConnected) {
            Intent register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(register);
        }

        VerifyBusiness();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the View is not being recreated upon logout. Upon logout whatever Activity that is hosting logged in interface should be terminated.

One way to solve this would be to run only one instance of the webpage access Activity by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the manifest file corresponding activity tag. So only one instance of the app is running and upon logout, the only instance is closed with all volatile associated memory being lost.

Another way would be to pass a parameter to login Intent such that if that value is one particular value, it signals that a new account has logged in and will recreate the View calling `recreate();`.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I already try recreate() but it doesn't work or I misused it. But I will try ```android:launchMode="singleInstance"``` thanks.